# Provider - Selector not updating UI for list items

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have a `ListView` consists of several `ListTile`s which have a trailing icon. The color of icon should change from transparent to green based on user tap. However the UI is not updating on user interaction.

The `ServiceModel` is like this.

```
class ProviderService extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List<String> totalNames = ['Somesh', 'Tarulata', 'Indranil', 'Satyajyoti', 'Biswas', 'Sajal', 'Kumar', 'Slipa', 'Sonam', 'Neelam'];

  List<String> _selectedNames = [];
  List<String> get selectedNames => _selectedNames;

  void updateselectedNames(String name) {
    bool isExists = _selectedNames.contains(name);

    if (isExists)
      _selectedNames.remove(name);
    else
      _selectedNames.add(name);

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The `ListView` goes like this.

```
class Members extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ProviderService plService = Provider.of<ProviderService>(context, listen: false);

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Selector<ProviderService, List<String>>(
          selector: (_, service) => service.selectedNames,
          builder: (context, selNames, child) {
            if (plService.totalNames.isEmpty) return child;

            return ListView.separated(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                String _name = plService.totalNames[index];

                return ListTile(
                  title: Text('$_name'),
                  trailing: Icon(
                    Icons.check_circle,
                    color: selNames.contains(_name) ? Colors.lightGreen : Colors.transparent,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    plService.updateselectedNames(_name),
                    print(selNames);
                  },
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (_, __) => Divider(),
              itemCount: plService.totalNames.length,
            );
          },
          child: Center(
            child: Text('No names have been found', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and of course the `main.dart` is like this.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => ProviderService(),
        child: Members(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Even though the list `selectedNames` updated, the UI remains same. What's going on wrong here ?

Answer (score 7):

You may add the shouldRebuild parameter of Selector and return true。like this:

```
Selector<ProviderService, List<String>>(
          selector: (_, service) => service.selectedNames,
          builder: (context, selNames, child) {...},
          shouldRebuild: (previous, next) => true,
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use a `Selector`, you have to make sure that the selected object is immutable.

```
Selector<ProviderService, List<String>>(
  selector: (_, service) => service.selectedNames,
  builder: (context, selNames, child) { ...},
),
```

`builder` will only get called once because your `selectedNames` object always stays the same. You are removing and adding items in the same array Object.

So, you should instead provide a new array in your `updateselectedNames`:

```
  void updateselectedNames(String name) {
    _selectedNames = _selectedNames.contains(name)
        ? _selectedNames.where((item) => item != name).toList()
        : [..._selectedNames, name];
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

My way would be like this for your scenario.

```
   class ProviderService extends ChangeNotifier {
      final List<Name> totalNames = [
         Name(name: 'Somesh', isTransparent: false),
         Name(name: 'Tarulata', isTransparent: false),
      ];
    
      List<Name> _selectedNames = [];
      List<Name> get selectedNames => _selectedNames;
    
      void updateselectedNames(int index) {
        var exist = _isExist(totalNames[index]);
        if(exist){
          _selectedNames.remove(totalNames[index]);
        } else {
          _selectedNames.add(totalNames[index]);
        }
        totalNames[index].isTransparent = !totalNames[index].isTransparent;
        notifyListeners();
      }

      bool _isExist(Name name) {
         var filter = _selectedNames.singleWhere(
          (element) => element.name == name.name,
          orElse: () => null,
         );
         return filter != null;
       }
    
    }

    class Name {
      String name;
      bool isTransparent;
      Name({this.name, this.isTransparent});
    }
```

And you can use `Selector` in `ListView` for every `ListTile`

```
Selector<ProviderService, Name>(
  selector: (_, service) => service.totalNames[index],
  builder: (context, name, child) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text('${name.name}'),
      trailing: Icon(
      Icons.check_circle,
      color: !name.isTransparent ? Colors.lightGreen : Colors.transparent,
    ),
    onTap: () {
      plService.updateselectedNames(index),
    },
);
```